# Universal norm of global function field.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

The kernel of global reciprocity map for a global field $k$ is given by intersection of norm groups of finite extension of $k$. In the case of number field I know that this is non-trivial and even has some explicit description. However, I managed to find no result in the case of global function field, other than the fact that the element in the universal norm group must be and $n$th power for any positive integer $n$.

So I would like to know:

$1.$ Is universal norm non-trivial in the case of global function field?

$2.$ If so is there an explicit description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that from Cohomology of number fields that this group is indeed trivial.